# window stations and desktops

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to launch an application on a hidden desktop but not getting much progress and can't find a detailed documentation on how what the desktops and window stations really are.  Here's my code with error handling removed (but beleive me it is there and is not catching any errors):

```
HWINSTA winSta = CreateWindowStation(_T("hiddenWinSta"), 0, 0, NULL);
SetProcessWindowStation(winSta);
HDESK desktop = CreateDesktop(_T("hiddenDesktop"), NULL, NULL, 0, DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW, NULL);
OpenDesktop(_T("hiddenDesktop"), 0, TRUE, GENERIC_ALL);
SetThreadDesktop(desktop)

HWINSTA r = GetProcessWindowStation();
printf("winsta: %x %x\n", r, winSta);
HDESK curdesk = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
printf("desktop: %x %x\n", curdesk, desktop);

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
//si.lpDesktop = _T("hiddenDesktop");
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
TCHAR szCommand[MAX_PATH];
_sntprintf_s(szCommand, MAX_PATH, _T("%s"), _T("c:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe"));
DWORD res = CreateProcess(NULL, szCommand, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

If I uncomment the si.lpDesktop line the process fails to start with the dreaded error 0x000142.  If I comment si.lpDesktop process starts on the current desktop.
What am I doing wrong?  Is it even possible to do what I want (i.e. launch a Windows GUI app completely invisible)?

Comment: What is the point of launching a *Windows GUI* app on an invisible desktop? A GUI is a "Graphical User Interface", meaning it expects to get info from or display info to a user.

Comment: Try uncomment `si.lpDesktop = _T("hiddenDesktop");` and comment `HWINSTA winSta = CreateWindowStation(_T("hiddenWinSta"), 0, 0, NULL);` `SetProcessWindowStation(winSta);`

Comment: @MK: Most apps that support automation (such as MS Office apps) allow you to automate them via COM, and they can be used invisibly without resorting to an "invisible desktop".

Comment: @KenWhite fine, I'll just ignore the app that I have to deal with and the fact that it in fact shows up when automated.  Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @MK: Why the snark? I was trying to clarify what you were asking. I'm not sure what I said that caused you to be rude in response, but I apologize for whatever that might be. I'll remove my comments. Good luck.

Comment: @KenWhite sorry, didn't mean to be rude, but I'm trying to do what I need to do and there is not much point in figuring out _why_ I need to do it, even if it is stupid.  There is 3rd party app, it needs to run,  and it would be better if it was invisible.  That's it.

Comment: You don't need a separate window station, you can create an additional desktop on the existing one.

Comment: @sergmat d'oh.  I was 100% sure I tried that but apparently I didn't.  Works fine.  If you rewrite this as an answer I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uncomment

```
si.lpDesktop = _T("hiddenDesktop");
```

comment

```
// HWINSTA winSta = CreateWindowStation(_T("hiddenWinSta"), 0, 0, NULL);
// SetProcessWindowStation(winSta);
```